# Problema con cache en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web, cache

Estoy teniendo graves problemas con la cache en AngularJS.

Tengo una pantalla de login, en la cuál cargo un par de variables desde el controlador, para según el cliente que acceda, cargue un valor u otro.

El problema es que en local y en mi red no hay problema, pero cuando acceden los clientes desde afuera de la red da un montón de problemas.

El problema que veo es el siguiente:

[image: Error cache angular]

No realiza carga desde API ni nada, simplemente importo un fichero javascript con los nombres de las variables a mostrar.

Tengo un controlador master en el cual importo el config.

```
$.getScript("js/config.js");
```

Dentro de este fichero es donde cargos las variables fijas

```
var nombreEmpresaLogin = "Stack";
```

Una vez cargadas, las muestro en el controlador del login.

```
$scope.nombreEmpresaLogin = nombreEmpresaLogin;
```

Lo que os comento a veces va bien a veces da error. Y parece un error de que no carga el javascript a la vez que la vista.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner tu código y/o alguna pantalla de la consola del navegador? Eso tiene mas pinta de error en el código que de otra cosa.

Comment: @Naimad Hola, adjunto breve explicación con el código, como ves, no tiene mucho misterio.

Comment: Debe ser un problema de orden de carga, que contiene el config.js y en que momento se carga?

Comment: stas seguro que tu aplicación de angular y tus modulos so estan cargando correctamente?

Comment: @Klaimmore es lo que me temo, debería cargarse como primer fichero de la web, pero no siempre es así y no se como forzar esa carga

Comment: @AlejoFlorez Si, es un error aleatorio

Comment: No trabajas con layouts, lo de aleatorio no lo entiendo bien.... porque no cargas los scripts con la etiqueta <scripts> de html?

Comment: @AlejoFlorez Probaré a importar el script al principio del condigo, pero como indico, lo que hago es un archivo config.js importarlo, pero lo dicho, pruebo y os paso feedback

Comment: Parece que lo que comentaba @Klaimmore es el error, lo que he hecho es, en la generación del archivo minificado insertarlo, no el link, sino el fichero completo.